# Pivot Charts in google Sheets by counting non-numeric data?

Tags: charts, google-sheets

I have a dataset that I'd like to summarize in chart form.  There are about 30 categories whose counts I'd like to display in a bar chart from about 300+ responses. I think a pivot table is probably the best way to do this, but when I create a pivot table and select multiple columns, each new column added gets entered as a sub-set of a previous column.  My data looks something like the following

```
ID    Country    Age    thingA    thingB    thingC    thingD    thingE    thingF
1      US        5-9                thB                 thD                thF
2      FI        5-9     thA                                               thF
3      GA        5-9     thA                                               thF                         
4      US        10-14                       thC
5      US        10-14              thB                                    thF                         
6      US        15-18                     
7      BR        5-9     thA                                                                                             
8      US        15-18                                  thD                thF                      
9      FI        10-14   thA
```

So, I'd like to be able to create an interactive chart that showed the counts of "thing" items; I'd then like to be able to filter based upon demographic data (e.g., Country, Age).  Notice that the data is non-numeric, so I have to use a CountA to see how many there are in each category.

Is there a simple way to display chart data that summarizes the counts and will allow me to filter based on different criteria?

Comment: If you are looking for a programmatic way or for a developer tool, this site could be the right place for your question but it's not clear that. See [ask] and the [tag:google-spreadsheet] excerpt and wiki for specific directions about how and where to ask questions about Google Sheets.

Answer (score 0):

The [`query`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) can summarize the data in the form you want. The fact that you have "thA", "thB", etc, instead of "1" complicates the matter, but one can transform the strings to numeric data on the fly.

Assuming the data you've shown is in the cells A1:I10, the following formula will summarize it:

```
=query({B2:C10, arrayformula(if(len(D2:I10), 1, 0))}, "select Col1, Col2, count(Col3), sum(Col3), sum(Col4), sum(Col5), sum(Col6), sum(Col7) group by Col1, Col2", 0)
```

Explanation:

- `{B2:C10, arrayformula(if(len(D2:I10), 1, 0))}` creates a table where the first two columns are your B,C (Country, Age) and the other six are filled with 1 or 0 depending on whether the cells in D-I are filled or not.
- `select Col1, Col2, count(Col3), sum(Col3), ... group by Col1, Col2` selects Country, Age, the total count of rows with this Country-Age combination, the number of rows with thingA for this Country-Age combination, etc.
- the last argument, 0, indicates there are no header rows in the table passed to the query.

It's possible to give labels to the columns returned by the query, using `label`: see [query language documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage). It would be something like

```
label Col1 'Country', Col2 'Age', count(Col3) 'Total count', sum(Col3) 'thingA count', ...
```

Comment: This answer explains how to use QUERY to summarize data but not how to do an interactive chart that is the core of the question.

Comment: Thanks for this response, btw.  Unfortunately, as Rubén indicated, I was looking for something interactive. I ended up going with Tableau in order to allow others to interact with the data.

Answer (score 0):

Add a Count column to your data with a "1" for whatever occurrence, this might solve your problem in the Pivot Table. I was just looking for a solution and thought about this. Working now for me.